# SVG coordinates - mask & use & x/y attribute combined

Tags: html, svg

I have a problem with SVG coordinates. I'm sure it's not a bug and it's probably explained somewhere in the documentation and therefore I don't question it. But for my needs I can't find other way to resolve the problem. Now to the point.

### TL;DR

In `SVG`, this

```html
<mask id="myMask" x="0" y="0">
  ...
</mask>
<use xlink:href="..." x="100" y="100" mask="#myMask">
```

changes the `<use>` *x* (or *y*) position together with the `<mask>` *x* (or *y*) position.

I want to keep the `<mask>` in its place.

## Longer explanation

#### Background

In my web application I have a `SVG` path. I use it in multiple places so I decided to use **the `<use>` element**. Now, in some places I wanted to hide part of the path so I use **`<mask>` element** with a rectangle in it. There's also a situation where there is a stack of the same path placed one below another. To achieve this I used the **`y` attribute** for one of the `<use>` elements.

#### The question

Unfortunately, when I change the `y` coordinate of the `<use>` the `<mask>` attached to it also changes its `y` coordinate. The situation doesn't occur on `<path>` element nor other elements.

Below is an example (for simplicity I used `<rect>` elements).
Run the snippet to see four squares placed next to each other (two red and two yellow). The grey overlay represents the mask's boundaries. Squares will rather look like rectangles because they're cut in the half of their height by the `<mask>`. As you can see in the code, red squares are *imported* by `<use>` element and yellow ones are placed directly with `<rect>` element. Also the second and the fourth square are both moved 500 units downwards. **My problem is clearly represented by the second square**. It should be cut exactly like the fourth square but I need to do it the `<use>` way.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 4000 1000">
    <defs>
        <rect id="svgRect" width="1000" height="1000"></rect>
        <mask id="svgIconMask10">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="4000" fill="#ffffff" height="500"></rect>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    
    <!-- Rectangle 1 -->
    <use xlink:href="#svgRect" y="0" fill="#E5584C" mask="url(#svgIconMask10)"></use>
    
    <!-- Rectangle 2 -->
    <use xlink:href="#svgRect" x="1000" y="300" fill="#E5584C" style="mask: url(#svgIconMask10);"></use>
    
    <!-- Rectangle 3 -->
    <rect x="2000" y="0" width="1000" height="1000" fill="#E5D24C" style="mask: url(#svgIconMask10);"></rect>
    
    <!-- Rectangle 4 -->
    <rect x="3000" y="300" width="1000" height="1000" fill="#E5D24C" style="mask: url(#svgIconMask10);"></rect>
    
    
    <!-- Mask area boundaries -->
    <rect fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-width="6px" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="500" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the mask to a `<g />` element and have the `<use />` positioned independently:

```
<g  style="mask: url(#svgIconMask10);">
  <use xlink:href="#svgRect" x="1000" y="300" fill="#E5584C"></use>
</g>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb1q8dwh/

Comment: So simple idea! Why didn't I figure it out? ;)